# How is the demonstrative pronoun "is" weaker than the others?

Tags: demonstrative-pronoun, demonstrative-adjective

Lately, I've been reading about demonstrative pronouns and adjectives. I'm fairly comfortable with *hic* and *ille*, but I'm not too sure about *is*. How is *is* weaker than the other demonstratives? When would you use *is* instead of the others?

Comment: It is often used in Genitive: I saw Augustus and his dog: *Augustum et canem eius vidi.* Not just any dog, or my dog, but A,'s dog.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't have a source for this answer, as it's based on my intuition from reading Latin texts, but here's my sense of the difference between *is* and *hic/iste/ille*.

*Hic/iste/ille* are strongly [deictic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deixis): that is, they have a kind of "pointing finger" meaning. They often point out objects in space (here, near you, over there); but they can also point out things in metaphorical or "discourse space" -- *this* thing I'm about to say, *that* thing you're saying, *that* thing someone said a long time ago.

*Is*, on the other hand, doesn't really point out a referent in any distinctive way; it just means "the one we're talking about". It's a way of referring to something that's strongly "discourse-active", i.e. currently activated as a topic of discussion in the speaker's and hearer's minds. This is why, used by itself, *is* gets translated as "he" (which presupposes that the listener knows who "he" is), while *hic* etc. get translated as "this/that one" (which points out a referent out of a set of possibilities).

Though you didn't ask about them, the spatial adverbs show the same distinction. There's *ibi, eo, inde* "in/to/from the place we're talking about", vs. *hic, huc, hinc* "in/to/from this place here", *istic, istuc, istinc* "in/to/from that place of yours", *illic, illuc, illinc* "in/to/from that place there".